# ACCPAC Tables

Tags: database, accpac

I'm doing some work with ACCPAC and don't have the benefit of any documentation.

Specifically, I'm looking for:

- ARCUS
- ARIBD
- ARIBH
- AROBL

If you could tell me what the columns are as well, that'd be doubly benificial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope these help you out:

http://www.priceconsulting.ab.ca/cgi-bin/accpac.cgi?dat=ARCUS
http://www.priceconsulting.ab.ca/cgi-bin/accpac.cgi?dat=ARIBD
http://www.priceconsulting.ab.ca/cgi-bin/accpac.cgi?dat=ARIBH
http://www.priceconsulting.ab.ca/cgi-bin/accpac.cgi?dat=AROBL

Comment: Thank you so much!  You just saved me hours of guessing!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database there should be a table that lists all of the tables and descriptions and another one with a complete field list.  Look for the sysdflds table for field descriptions and sydtabl for table descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to their madness...

AH  Sage Accpac HRMS Payroll Link
AP  Accounts Payable
AR  Accounts Receivable
AS  Administrative Services 
BK  Bank Services
CP  Canadian Payroll
CS  Common Services 
CT  Cdn PR Tax Update Jul. 1, 2009
FA  Sage FAS Integration
GL  General Ledger
GP  G/L Subledger Services
IC  Inventory Control 
OE  Order Entry
PM  Project and Job Costing
PO  Purchase Orders
TX  Tax Services
UP  US Payroll
UT  US PR Tax Update Oct. 1, 2009
ZC  G/L Consolidations
ZI  Intercompany Transactions

Answer (score 0):

You need to use internet Explorer, 
For all Modules like AR, OE etc..

http://sageaom.kcsvar.com/AOM2012/Advantage.xml

You can find all  AR tables here :

http://sageaom.kcsvar.com/AOM2012/AR0036.xml

for Example , AROBL : 
http://sageaom.kcsvar.com/AOM2012/AR.xml